# Delete a pointer member in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

can someone explain to me, why it is necessary to also define the copy and assignment operator in this simple case.

```
struct A {
 A() {
   ptr = new int;
 }
 ~A() {
   delete ptr;
 }
int* ptr;
};
```

Because if i don't define them, i can only resize the vector once, and the programm breaks after the second resize. I would like to understand whats going on.

```
int main() {
std::vector<A> a_vec;
a_vec.resize(4);
a_vec.resize(5); // program breaks
}
```

Also if i dont define the deconstructor the program works fine, but i have to define the deconstructor in order to delete the pointer, right?

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Think about what the default copy ctor and copy assignment op do with `ptr`.

Comment: Also related to "deep-copy" and "shallow copy"